# Prank'd or how to get suspended for a month

Tags: support

So this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142152/pavel) got suspended for a month, I figure after he posted this [deleted post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49726975/guys-downvote-me-please).

I wonder if this guy just got "prank'd", because someone had access to his PC or even got hacked. The penalty box seems wierd here, because it seems unlikly that the user intended this post.

If my suspicion is right, can the user get unlocked (assuming he gets in touch with SO) or does he have to wait for the month in any case?

Does he get an email about what happend?

Comment: Or it is just what it looks like, a user behaving pretty badly.  And not just with that nasty hate post.

Comment: We shouldn't put much efforts in deciding whether or not users were hacked before submitting such posts. If that's indeed the case, I believe OP will know how to be in touch with the system and explains what really happened.

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: People throwing hissy fits like that is in no way unusual for this site.

Comment: @rene because I am curios, what happens. And if he gets notified that something like this happend on the account. I would want to know.

Comment: In my refactor before the post I accidentily deleted the question about the notification.

Comment: suspensions and any resolutions are between the user and the mod team. Beyond curiosity I don't think answers to this questions can be general applicable, at least I can't imagine beyond a link to contact us will be offered here.

Comment: They get a mod message in their inbox and that is also send to their known email address.

Comment: @rene I wouldn't be surprised if it's not the first mod message to the user asked about here because their rep history shows fairly suspicious voting correction that happened about 3 weeks ago

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Moderators usually do not discuss specific suspensions, the reasons are private between moderators and the user.

In general, we are aware that sometimes accounts get pranked; such cases are ususally quite obvious and we have the option to reset all sessions to force the user to reauthenticate. We can also use a short suspension period to put an immediate end to any pranking in case it was the user themselves doing this.

In less obvious cases, the suspended user has the opportunity to explain their side in a response to the suspension message, which is sent to their account inbox and registered email address.

Comment: Thx for the clarification. I was not directly interested in that user, but it made me curios.

Answer (score 8):

> The penalty box seems wierd here, because it seems unlikly that the user intended this post.

Intended or not, the fact remains that abusive behaviour was committed from this account. It's not SO's responsibility to figure out whether or not this was done as a prank or not. If it was a prank, the user can contact SO with a plea to unban him.